# Python 3 Program to download Homestuck

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been working for a program over the last few days which should download a range of pages from the webcomic [Homestuck](http://mspaintadventures.com). I've created a working version in python 3, but it is horribly inefficient. Can anyone see ways to improve and shorten this code?

```
import urllib.request
range1 = int(input("Enter the 1st page you want: "))
range2 = int(input("Enter the last page you want: ")) + 1
current = range1 + 1900
final = range2 + 1900
page = ''
nextPage = ''
while current != final:
    page = str(current)
    nextPage = str(current+1)
    while len(page) != 6:
        page = '0'+ page
    while len(nextPage) != 6:
        nextPage = '0'+ nextPage
    html = 'http://www.mspaintadventures.com/?s=6&p='+page
    site = urllib.request.urlopen(html)
    s = site.read()
    s = s.decode("utf8")
    s = s.replace("<!-- end comic content -->", "<!-- begin comic content -->")
    s = s.replace("http://cdn.mspaintadventures.com/storyfiles/hs2/", "")
    s = s.replace("?s=6&p=" + str(nextPage), str(int(nextPage))+".html")
    s = s.replace(page+"/"+page, page)
    a,b,c = s.split('<!-- begin comic content -->')
    b = "<title> Page " + page + "</title>" + b
    t = open(str(current)+".html", 'w+')
    t.write(b)
    t.close()
    page = str((int(page)-1900))
    while len(page) != 5:
        page = '0'+ page

    t = open(str(current)+".html", 'a')
    swfname=page+".swf"
    t.write("<object width='1000' height='1000'> <param name='movie' value='"+swfname+"'>")
    t.write("<embed src="+swfname+" width=650 height=450>")
    t.write("</embed>")
    t.write("</object>")
    t.close()
    try:
        img = "http://cdn.mspaintadventures.com/storyfiles/hs2/"+page+".gif"
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(img, page+".gif")
    except:
        try:
            img = "http://cdn.mspaintadventures.com/storyfiles/hs2/"+page+"_1.gif"
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(img, page+"_1.gif")
            img = "http://cdn.mspaintadventures.com/storyfiles/hs2/"+page+"_2.gif"
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(img, page+"_2.gif")
        except:
            try:
                img = "http://cdn.mspaintadventures.com/storyfiles/hs2/"+page+"/"+page+".swf"
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(img, page+".swf")
            except:
                print("Image "+img+" failed to download")
    print ("Page " + str(page) + " of " + str(final-1901) + " downloaded")
    current+=1
    print("DONE")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main performance issue is the *blocking nature of your script*. You don't process the next url until you are done with the current. Think of using asynchronous tools like [`Scrapy` web-scraping framework](https://scrapy.org/) which is based on `twisted`; or something like [`grequests`](https://github.com/kennethreitz/grequests).

Other notes:

- if you would stick to synchronous approach, switch to [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/), initialize a session ([`requests.Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects)) once and reuse - this should be faster than using `urllib.request`
- when you generate HTML files, pre-define a template with placeholders, render the template on the fly filling up the placeholders. You may use a template engine like [`mako`](http://www.makotemplates.org/) or [`Jinja2`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/), or use the built-in `str.format()`
- it also looks like you are reopening each of the generated files twice - once for the initial write in the `w+` mode and then to append in `a` mode

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a go. As for your 3rd note, is there a better way than this?

Comment: @JammyDodger I was thinking about keeping the file open until you are done writing into it..open once per iteration..thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to append to a file without reopening?

Comment: @JammyDodger I think you can keep the file open in the `w` mode and continue writing into it..may be I'm missing something..

Comment: But when I write in 'w' mode, it overwrites the file. Or maybe if I keep the file open it will just append?

Comment: @JammyDodger yup, exactly, don't reopen, keep it open and close it at the end, when you are done writing into it.